# LINQ and INFORMATION.SCHEMA

Tags: linq

I have a really strange issue.

As I did not manage to access the views INFORMATION_SCHEMA.* I created some views that are simple mirrors of these system views.

The views are working fine in SSMS.

Next step: I created a console c# project, nuget EntityFramework 6.1.3, and added a model using the wizard. During this step, I selected my custom views and got the corresponding DbSet statements.

I then used the entity lists as follows:

```
Model myModel = new Model();
foreach(var row in myModel.INFORMATION_SCHEMA_COLUMNS)
   Console.WriteLine($"{row.TABLE_NAME}.{row.COLUMN_NAME}");
```

Now the issue: I get the correct number of rows, and the TABLE_NAME info is correct, but the COLUMN_NAME is filled with the first column per table.

So, If I have columns name1, name2, name3 in table Names, I will get

```
Names.name1
Names.name1
Names.name1
```

instead of

```
Names.name1
Names.name2
Names.name3
```

Interestingly, the query that goes to sql server is correct, when I issue this very same query in SSMS I get the correct data. So it seems EF is doing something here.

More confusing: access to INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES is working ok

Comment: This is because the EF mappings don't have the correct primary key. Make sure the PKs include all properties that identify the view's rows uniquely.

Comment: works like a charm!! Thanks